# iOS CollectionView as a View - Is this a good practice?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have seen a code, that sets the ViewController's view to be a collectionView.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   view = collectionView
}
```

As much as it sounds right, I feel this is a bad practice. If I were to add a subview or another UI element, I would need a container and adding it to a collectionview doesn't seem right.

Comment: You would want to do it in `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad` but there isn't anything wrong with it.  `UICollectionViewController` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan points out in his comment, `UICollectionViewController` has a collection view as it's content view.

Personally, I find this limiting and annoying, since it means that the only thing the view controller can manage is a single collection view. It is, however, a valid way to do things (although, as Dan also points out, you should do this in `loadView()` instead of `viewDidLoad`. `loadView()` lets you create you view hierarchy in code rather than creating it from a Storyboard/XIB file.

If you're going to do that, though, why not just use a `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: Makes sense. Also this view controller doesn't have a storyboard.

Comment: `UICollectionViewController`'s `view` is a `UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView`. `UICollectionViewController`'s `collectionView` is a `UICollectionView`, and is a subview of the controller's `view`.